# Divergence Dedekind zeta function

Tags: analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta, zeta-functions

Let $K$ be a number field, $\mathcal O_K$ be its ring of integers, T a positive integer and $N$ the norm function. 
Give an upper bound (in T) for 
$$\sum_{I\leq \mathcal O_K: N(I)\leq T} \frac{1}{N(I)}$$